# How can i remove multiple numbers from a list that add to a target number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

For example, given

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

target = 6
```

How could I remove the 2 and 4 from the list so the list returned is `[1, 3, 5]`?

This is what I have so far:

```
def update(numbers, target_sum):
    updated_list = []
    for num in numbers:
        if num != target_sum:
            updated_list.append(num)
    return updated_list

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
target_sum = 6

print(update(numbers, target_sum))
```

Obviously this only works if the target is in the list. I have no idea how to do this with 2 or more numbers that add up to the target.

Comment: Why does it remove 2 and 4, but not 1 and 5?

Comment: Either combination is fine, just using 2 and 4 as an example.

Comment: Since there is no limit to how many numbers can be added up to the target, this also means you can have many possible combinations that add up to your target value. You would need to use recursion to return all possible combinations (or maybe in your case, the first combination possible).

Comment: Do you have to find one combination or all possible? Is the order of the numbers important? Will they always be given in ascending order?

Comment: Just one combination. Once one combination is found the list with those numbers removed should be returned. The order of the numbers is not important, and they will always be given in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cute solution: generate all binary numbers with `len(numbers)` digits. For each binary digit, add up the corresponding number from the input, and if they sum to `target_sum`, return it.

The binary digits are then used to *remove* those numbers from the input list.

```py
import itertools

def update(numbers, target_sum):
    for choices in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(numbers)):
        total = sum(number*choice for choice, number in zip(choices, numbers))
        if total == target_sum:
            return [number for choice, number in zip(choices, numbers) if not choice]

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
target_sum = 6

print(update(numbers, target_sum))
# [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools.combination](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) on the list based on the length of the list should work:

```
# Imports
from itertools import combinations
from typing import Iterable


# Definitions
def update(numbers: Iterable[int], target_sum: int) -> list[int]:
    """Removes the first combination of numbers that add up to a sum"""
    
    # Convert any iterable to a list
    numbers = list(numbers)
    
    # Find the combo (if there is one)
    for l in range(1, len(numbers) + 1):
        found = False
        for combo in combinations(numbers, l):
            if sum(combo) == target_sum:
                found = True
                break
        
        if found:
            break
    else:
        return None
    
    # Return values
    for num in combo:
        numbers.remove(num)
    
    return numbers


# Tests
print(update(range(1,8), 6)) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
print(update(range(1,6), 6)) # [2, 3, 4]
print(update([1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 3], 2)) # None
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want the first combination found returned and your combination can have 2 or more numbers, I would suggest approaching this with recursion.

```py
def update(numbers, curr_idx, curr_sum, target_sum, curr_combo):
    if curr_sum == target_sum:
        # Base case: current sum equals target sum, so we found a valid combination
        return curr_combo
    elif curr_sum > target_sum or curr_idx >= len(numbers):
        # Base case: current sum exceeds target sum or we have reached the end of the list
        return None
    else:
        # Recursive case: include the current number and explore further possibilities
        curr_num = numbers[curr_idx]
        curr_combo.append(curr_num)
        result = update(numbers, curr_idx + 1, curr_sum + curr_num, target_sum, curr_combo)
        if result:
            # If a valid combination is found, return it
            return result
        curr_combo.pop()  # Remove the current number and explore without it
        
        # Explore without including the current number
        return update(numbers, curr_idx + 1, curr_sum, target_sum, curr_combo)

# Example usage:
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
target_sum = 6
result = update(numbers, 0, 0, target_sum, [])
print(result) # [1, 2, 3]
```

The main thing to note here is you are not generating all possible combinations and then testing each one individually, but generating a combination one at a time and checking to see if it adds to the target sum, so it's more time-efficient. And the second it has found a valid combination, it will stop the recursion process and return that.

If you want to generate all valid combinations, you can use the following:

```py
def update(numbers, curr_idx, curr_sum, target_sum, curr_combo):
    if curr_sum == target_sum:
        # Base case: current sum equals target sum, so we found a valid combination
        print(curr_combo)
    elif curr_sum > target_sum or curr_idx >= len(numbers):
        # Base case: current sum exceeds target sum or we have reached the end of the list
        return
    else:
        # Recursive case: include the current number and explore further possibilities
        curr_num = numbers[curr_idx]
        curr_combo.append(curr_num)
        update(numbers, curr_idx + 1, curr_sum + curr_num, target_sum, curr_combo)
        curr_combo.pop()  # Remove the current number and explore without it
        
        # Explore without including the current number
        update(numbers, curr_idx + 1, curr_sum, target_sum, curr_combo)

# Example usage:
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
target_sum = 6
update(numbers, 0, 0, target_sum, [])

# Output:
"""
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 5]
[2, 4]
[6]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with exponential time complexity so it will eventually take an inordinate amount of time so solve as your lists and target get larger.

For relatively small lists, recursion is an easy way to solve it:

```
def removeSum(N,S):
    for i,n in enumerate(N):          # try every position
        if n>S:  continue             # number too large, move on 
        if n==S: return N[:i]+N[i+1:] # matching number is a solution 
        r = removeSum(N[i+1:],S-n)    # call function with remaining
        if r is not None:             #      items and rest of target
            return N[:i]+r            # combine removals
```

output:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
target  = 6
print(removeSum(numbers,target))
# [4, 5]

numbers = [2,3,4,6,8]
target  = 7
print(removeSum(numbers,target))
# [2, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest for two-sum, keep a map of values to indexes. Has linear complexity in both time and space:

```
def update(numbers, target_sum):
    inds = {}
    for j, num in enumerate(numbers):
        if (d := target_sum - num) in inds and (i := inds[d]) != j:
            return numbers[:i] + numbers[i+1:j] + numbers[j+1:]
        inds[num] = j
    # do whatever you want in case target_sum is not found

>>> update([1,2,3,4,5], 6)
[1, 3, 5]
>>> update([1,2,3,4,5], 7)
[1, 2, 5]
>>> update([1,2,3,4,5], 8)
[1, 2, 4]
>>> update([3,3,3,3,3], 6)
[3, 3, 3]
```